# laravel 403This action is unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, updates, http-status-code-403

Can you helpe me? I can't update sql's tables.
Laravel laravel 403This action is unauthorized.

Last stable version laravel and  php7.4

class UsersController extends Controller

```
public function updateAuthor(Request $request,User $user)
    {

        $user = \Auth::user();
        $id =  $user->id;

        dd($user);

       //recoger datos del formulario       
       $name = $request->input('name');
       $email = $request-> input('email');

        //asignar nuevos valores  al objeto del usuario
        $user -> name =$name;
        $user -> email = $email;

        $user->roles()->sync($request->role);

        //dd($user);
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index')->with(['message' => 'OK, permisos cambiados']);
    }
```

roourweb.php

```
Route::post('/updateAuthor/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@updateAuthor')->name('updateAuthor')->middleware('can: can:manage-users');
```

AuthServiceProvider

```
Gate::define('manage-users', function($user){

           return $user->hasAnyRoles(['admin']);

       });
```

web.php

```
 <form action ="{{route('updateAuthor',['id' => $user->id])}}" method="POST">
```

UpdateUserRequest

```
    public function authorize()
    {

        return true;
    }



public function ownAutor(Author $author)
{
  return true;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1QA9.png)

Comment: Can you print and look at the value returing from Gate?
```$user->hasAnyRoles(['admin']);```

Comment: Yes, I can do all with 'admin'. The problem is author I can't  save change in DB. I don't  why. Because I can list all users  with 'author'. I have made a personalized request  too and nothing.

Comment: You won't be able to update author because you are adding a manage-users middleware on your route which requires user role admin.